# Extracting float from string in Google docs

Tags: regex, google-sheets

In my Google Sheet, I am trying to extract a specific float (0.068359375) from a Test String using Regex:

```
PC190B48KNK - 2 items (0.068359375 cu ft @ $0.08, $0.08 min)
```

Regex function:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A1,"[+-]?([0-9]*[.])?[0-9]+{6,}")
```

The regex function works when I test it in [Rubular](http://rubular.com/) but in Sheets I am getting the error:

> Function REGEXEXTRACT parameter 2 value "[+-]?([0-9]*[.])?[0-9]+{6,}"
>   is not a valid regular expression.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Rubular uses Onigmo regex engine, Google sheets uses RE2. It makes no sense using an incompatible regex tester unless you know the differences and know what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

Error just because want to get 6 or more variants but set + too. Try this one :

```
[+-]?([0-9]*[.])?\d{6,}
```

Comment: That is giving me the result of "0." when I want: "0.068359375"

Answer (score 0):

Actually, even Rubular says "*Oops, there was an error handling your regex. We'll try again in a few seconds.*" Your regex is invalid because you are using `[0-9]+{6,}`, a `+` quantifier followed with `{6,}`, a limiting quantifier, which is forbidden.

If you meant to match six or more digits after an optional sequence of zero or more digits followed with a `.` char, you can use

```
[+-]?(?:[0-9]*\.)?[0-9]{6,}
```

Note:

- Use the [non-capturing group](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3512471/3832970) for the `[0-9]*\.` part to avoid getting the group value as a result
- Use `[0-9]{6,}` to match six or more digits.